# Is there an effective way of mining html elements for selenium using python (and avoiding the dev tools). If this can be done with BeautifulSoup, how?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, browser-automation

I am writing a selenium webdriver script to automate the process of updating an event registration portal.

***A picture of the UI is linked below.***

I was able to successfully log in to the web portal. By using XPATH elements copied from chrome dev tools. I was also able to successfully automate switching between the individual folders on the left hand side of the screen (2018, 2017, ..., Canada, US, ..., Vancouver, Kelowna, ...). Keep in mind that the was I was able to do this was by manually coping individual XPATH elements for each clickable folder link as shown in the script below.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Computer/Downloads/chromedriver")

# Go to the regOnline homepage
driver.get("######LoginPage#####")
driver.get("#####LinkedUIPage#####")
# the page is ajaxy so the title is originally this:
print ("print " + driver.title)


# find the username and password element
userElement = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMaster_txtLogin")
passElement = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMaster_txtPassword")

# find the login button element
logInElement = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Sign In")


# type in account information
userElement.send_keys("#####")
passElement.send_keys("#####")

# log into the webpage (hit the enter button)
logInElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# xpath elements
calgaryXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/div/span[2]'
edmontonXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/div/span[2]'
fortNelsonXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[3]/div/span[2]'
fortStJohnXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[4]/div/span[2]'
halifaxXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[5]/div/span[2]'
kamloopsXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[6]/div/span[2]'
kelownaXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[7]/div/span[2]'
ottawaXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[10]/div/span[2]'
princeGeorgeXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/div/span[2]'
saskatoonXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[12]/div/span[2]'
thunderBayXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[13]/div/span[2]'
torontoXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[14]/div/span[2]'
vancouverXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[15]/div/span[2]'
whitehorseXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[16]/div/span[2]'
williamsLakeXPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[17]/div/span[2]'

page2018XPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/div/img'
canada2018XPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphDialog_cpMgrMain_trUserNodes"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[1]/div/img'

# find city element
calgary = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, calgaryXPATH)
edmonton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, edmontonXPATH)
fortNelson = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, fortNelsonXPATH)
fortStJohn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, fortStJohnXPATH)
halifax = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, halifaxXPATH)
kamloops = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, kamloopsXPATH)
kelowna = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, kelownaXPATH)
ottawa = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ottawaXPATH)
princeGeorge = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, princeGeorgeXPATH)
saskatoon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, saskatoonXPATH)
thunderBay = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, thunderBayXPATH)
toronto = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, torontoXPATH)
whitehorse = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, whitehorseXPATH)
vancouver = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, vancouverXPATH)
williamsLake = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, williamsLakeXPATH)

page2018 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, page2018XPATH)
canada2018 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, canada2018XPATH)

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)

def goToPage(xpath, sec):
    actions.move_to_element(xpath)
    actions.click(xpath)
    actions.perform()
    time.sleep(sec)

# testing individual page access
goToPage(page2018,3)
goToPage(canada2018,3)



# save page html
#html = driver.page_source

#soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Referencing the image, I need to access all the individual event links in the mid-right hand portion of the UI, the event log. To copy each XPATH element from each link would be laborious and unnecessary. Further, these would be constantly updating and I would need a method to access individual elements without manually copying and pasting from the browser's dev tools.

[UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJswg.jpg)

QUESTION:
- Is there an effective way of mining html elements for selenium using python (and avoiding the dev tools).

-- Is it possible to do this with beautiful soup by parsing the HTML's DOM
-- If the proposed method extends to any elements in the UI, all the better.

**NOTE** - I am unaware of how to do this in beautiful soup, if possible.

Regards,
J

Comment: Did you try to learn how to write your own XPath/CSS selectors? This is the best and most reliable way to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, this was a helpful answer. I am now just parsing elements by manipulating xpath strings.